# Coloring maximum, minimum and median price path to a specific color in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Currently I have a data table "test_data" of 20 simulated price paths. A snippet of the data looks something like this:

```
Month variable     value
1       V1         1.0000000
2       V1         1.0107850
3       V1         1.0265488
4       V1         1.0636623
5       V1         1.0941731
6       V1         1.1097758
7       V1         1.1116170
8       V1         1.1229932
9       V1         1.1779669
10      V1         1.1610330
11      V1         1.1408806
1       V2         1.0000000
2       V2         1.0109236
3       V2         1.0053303
4       V2         1.0126677
5       V2         1.0461632
6       V2         1.0747788
7       V2         1.0997711
8       V2         1.1196782
9       V2         1.1354743
10      V2         1.1602896
11      V2         1.1596831
1       V3         1.0000000
2       V3         1.0572598
3       V3         1.0374854
```

Each of the 20 price paths V(1 to 20) starts from 1 and ends up at a certain value. I have graphed the 20 price paths using ggplot as

```
ggplot(test_data, aes(Month,value, col=variable)) + 
  geom_line()+
  ggtitle("Simulated Price Paths") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

which gives the following graph

[image]

I would like to have three specific price paths colored as black and with thicker lines:

-the price path ending at the highest value at month 11

-lowest path ending value at month 11

-median value at month 11

I am new to ggplot and unsure how to implement this at all. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another column that specifies the variables that you want to be black.You can either make another dataframe that has that column or add that column to your original dataframe. I think it's easier in this case to just have a separate dataframe so you don't have to play around with the `scale_color_*` functions. And FYI, you should provide your data in text format for people to more easily help. The `dput` function in R allows you to do so easily.

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data = expand.grid(Month = 1:11,variable=paste0('V',1:20),stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(value=runif(nrow(.)))
dput(test_data) # the data is shown in code cell below the graph

# make a df that says which variables have the max/min/median month 11 value
foo = test_data %>% filter(Month == 11) %>%
  # order the value column
  arrange(value) %>%
  # add columns to find min, max, and "median" the middle value
  mutate(row_num = row_number(),
         new_col = if_else(row_num == 1,'min',
                           if_else(row_num ==  nrow(.),'max',
                                   # may have to play with median because no value guaranteed to exactly equal the median
                                   if_else(row_num == round(nrow(.)/2),'median','other')))) %>%
  select(variable,new_col)

# add that new variable to the data based on the variable column
test_data_with_classifier = test_data %>%
  left_join(foo,by='variable') %>%
  filter(new_col %in% c('min','max','median'))

# build your initial plot but remove the color aesthetic and data from the ggplot call
# so it doesn't apply to second geom_line call
ggplot(mapping=aes(Month,value)) +
  # original geom_line
  geom_line(aes(color=variable),data=test_data) +
  ggtitle("Simulated Price Paths") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  # new geom_line to plot the black min,max,median data
  geom_line(data=test_data_with_classifier,mapping=aes(group=new_col),
            color='black',size=1)
```

[image: new graph]

```
structure(list(Month = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L), variable = c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", 
"V1", "V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", 
"V2", "V2", "V2", "V2", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", 
"V3", "V3", "V3", "V3", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", 
"V4", "V4", "V4", "V4", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", 
"V5", "V5", "V5", "V5", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", 
"V6", "V6", "V6", "V6", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", 
"V7", "V7", "V7", "V7", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", 
"V8", "V8", "V8", "V8", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", 
"V9", "V9", "V9", "V9", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", 
"V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V10", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", 
"V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V11", "V12", "V12", 
"V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", "V12", 
"V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", "V13", 
"V13", "V13", "V14", "V14", "V14", "V14", "V14", "V14", "V14", 
"V14", "V14", "V14", "V14", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", 
"V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V15", "V16", "V16", "V16", 
"V16", "V16", "V16", "V16", "V16", "V16", "V16", "V16", "V17", 
"V17", "V17", "V17", "V17", "V17", "V17", "V17", "V17", "V17", 
"V17", "V18", "V18", "V18", "V18", "V18", "V18", "V18", "V18", 
"V18", "V18", "V18", "V19", "V19", "V19", "V19", "V19", "V19", 
"V19", "V19", "V19", "V19", "V19", "V20", "V20", "V20", "V20", 
"V20", "V20", "V20", "V20", "V20", "V20", "V20"), value = c(0.3207616454456, 
0.763921687379479, 0.816522044595331, 0.749660312896594, 0.59870492015034, 
0.598363760858774, 0.724914398510009, 0.209003237076104, 0.17182691837661, 
0.724648888222873, 0.971318073105067, 0.369079714873806, 0.766701503191143, 
0.80729194264859, 0.511416860157624, 0.944176482968032, 0.0978654811624438, 
0.716958795208484, 0.38553729141131, 0.327095735818148, 0.918577790725976, 
0.865334192989394, 0.834687531692907, 0.638412003172562, 0.199683424085379, 
0.109074046369642, 0.584284831071272, 0.675479859812185, 0.713516661897302, 
0.0794180030934513, 0.384025492705405, 0.828940884210169, 0.699888165574521, 
0.735423399368301, 0.907396653899923, 0.248153271153569, 0.65956291789189, 
0.606529506854713, 0.516759118298069, 0.425723660970107, 0.162580149481073, 
0.610716496128589, 0.829937220551074, 0.00947263417765498, 0.511702742660418, 
0.652116083307192, 0.590301762800664, 0.909111243207008, 0.952054579043761, 
0.799994048662484, 0.158715128898621, 0.809286607196555, 0.0451009501703084, 
0.725396532332525, 0.0322660498786718, 0.112002467270941, 0.613799379440024, 
0.362014023819938, 0.271398104028776, 0.215616049477831, 0.307330428389832, 
0.757429565768689, 0.689513321500272, 0.408647255739197, 0.343476827954873, 
0.996903440682217, 0.685957340057939, 0.286161876749247, 0.0998274721205235, 
0.349568751640618, 0.448729029623792, 0.109180265571922, 0.606069714995101, 
0.744512610835955, 0.094664296368137, 0.502116194460541, 0.501746303169057, 
0.43027435336262, 0.358490471262485, 0.445414373651147, 0.299434100743383, 
0.484706832794473, 0.886581416241825, 0.662599268835038, 0.0641198861412704, 
0.834478059783578, 0.121147126657888, 0.912385334260762, 0.821587839862332, 
0.172848681919277, 0.889836875488982, 0.329370712861419, 0.72060881392099, 
0.952831936301664, 0.738097631372511, 0.15180463087745, 0.808533443138003, 
0.191091127460822, 0.721191958058625, 0.204728928627446, 0.358556402148679, 
0.274529718095437, 0.758775806752965, 0.842871483648196, 0.432739966316149, 
0.59929970279336, 0.86859522620216, 0.360078621422872, 0.182892573997378, 
0.453561760019511, 0.0182492395397276, 0.6718317004852, 0.193607804365456, 
0.352003240492195, 0.655018073506653, 0.00389497983269393, 0.212779281195253, 
0.382988286204636, 0.302621328504756, 0.826272390317172, 0.965064536314458, 
0.768436536425725, 0.486362407449633, 0.192464913008735, 0.126183372689411, 
0.642314247321337, 0.067070194054395, 0.214890752686188, 0.559360482031479, 
0.600042793899775, 0.062608469510451, 0.327152049634606, 0.567664009751752, 
0.184450926026329, 0.99510698672384, 0.896966585190967, 0.796468431828544, 
0.646989026572555, 0.609200611012056, 0.661479892674834, 0.0861319426912814, 
0.0504770788829774, 0.992110759951174, 0.242711320985109, 0.981608556117862, 
0.116498072398826, 0.32264380552806, 0.452757821884006, 0.427302462747321, 
0.604806548450142, 0.134451362304389, 0.89202874340117, 0.365254261530936, 
0.130264255683869, 0.953156332718208, 0.820071451831609, 0.516127375187352, 
0.265554389217868, 0.51679350156337, 0.994173315353692, 0.0734945498406887, 
0.851095038000494, 0.396602528868243, 0.711098247207701, 0.382826760644093, 
0.895369519013911, 0.684021956985816, 0.837272961856797, 0.94457382359542, 
0.843695271993056, 0.216426289873198, 0.412310103652999, 0.984022463904694, 
0.0559382131323218, 0.374431659234688, 0.106870166258886, 0.237605754984543, 
0.601918715750799, 0.634860647842288, 0.376950473990291, 0.625570185715333, 
0.163354992168024, 0.221454897429794, 0.174484543036669, 0.35767737054266, 
0.829755877144635, 0.435555089730769, 0.67005174444057, 0.995627127122134, 
0.126283596735448, 0.455085375113413, 0.707600452937186, 0.546373196877539, 
0.950488998554647, 0.881859563523903, 0.995245850877836, 0.692439902573824, 
0.279077719897032, 0.542088820366189, 0.809259225381538, 0.517200969392434, 
0.403256884543225, 0.984078820096329, 0.0350806810893118, 0.58890008716844, 
0.0394498331006616, 0.71059784758836, 0.176494438899681, 0.247808628715575, 
0.692503416212276, 0.581507980125025, 0.0534774195402861, 0.146403533173725, 
0.990876362659037, 0.654077555285767, 0.655882946448401, 0.627923337742686, 
0.422042631078511, 0.446751018986106, 0.110627941554412)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-220L))
```